# Why did Maia compare helicopters to cars?

Tags: monsterverse, godzilla-vs-kong

Maia just landed on aircraft carrier, speaks to Dr Nathan:

> Maia: I know you people think you're cutting-edge, but these prototypes we're loaning you will make what you've been **flying look like used Miatas**.

Why did Maia compare helicopters to cars?

Comment: Comparison: [tv tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CrapsackOnlyByComparison).

Comment: What I want to know is what’s wrong with a used Miata?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Miata (otherwise known as a Mazda MX-5) is a medium-performance sports car, basically the purchase of choice for those that couldn't afford a genuine supercar.

Those from the 1980s and 1990s look *decidedly dated* when compared to current sports cars (which will, in their turn, look dated compared to whatever comes along in the 2030s).

[image] vs. [image].

Maia is pointing out that their new [hovercars](https://godzilla.fandom.com/wiki/Hollow_Earth_Aerial_Vehicle) will make their 'cutting edge' helicopters look like crap *by comparison*.

[image]
vs.
[image]